# how to give if condition based on count using autocomplete data in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I have one input-text box with a submit button. By using an autocomplete method when I search for related data, if data is in database it should do the search,  otherwise it should be inserted in database when I click submit. Here in my code I am getting the database result in "source" using ajax in JS.

```
 <?php  $search = "<script>source</script>";
   if(count($search) > 0){
        $onclickEvent = "onclick='return searchQuestionName();'";
        }else{
        $onclickEvent = "onclick='return InsertQuestionsInfo();'";
        } ?>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <input type="text" id="questionname" name="name" placeholder="Search through Questions" required=""/>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="FormSubmit" <?php echo $onclickEvent;?> class="mc-btn btn-style-1" style="width:100px;">Submit</button>
```

Below is my autocomplete Script:

```
<script>
    $( "#questionname" ).autocomplete({
      source: rootUrl+"includes/ajax/ajax_chat.php?action=searchQuestionName"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Its not really clear if you are saying there is a problem with this code (there is of course) or whether you want us to code some extra functionality for you?

Comment: actually when i type something if data is there by using autocomplete it will display .when it display then i click submit my search function should be work otherwise my insert function should be work

Comment: `if(count("#questionname") > 0)` - is it possible in PHP?

Comment: Unfortunately it compiles with that code but it will not do what is expected

Comment: no,Its  not possible.I am confused here  what to give in count if(count("#questionname") > 0)

Comment: This php script just above the text box or where you have placed?

Comment: Actually the closer I look the less sence this code makes.

Comment: Your question looks very less information and code snippet. Please explain your question in detailed manner and provide necessary code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

From My understanding, You cannot define the onclick event before you start typing search term.

You have 2 choices,

1/ textbox id questionname, on blur you send an ajax request and find the count. then bind the click event to the submit button according to the count you get from ajax.

2/ Just submit this form to a php file and write your business flow.(find search term's count, if no count just insert the search term before proceed you business logic).